# cin >> fails with bigger numbers but works with smaller ones?

Tags: c++, cin

Why does `cin` fail, when I enter a number like: 3999999999 but it works for smaller numbers like: 5 ?

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    if (std::cin.fail())
        std::cout << "Something sucks!";
    else  
        std::cout << n;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the output of `cout << sizeof(int);`? If that is 4, 3,999,999,999 makes a 32-bit signed int overflow.

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
std::cout << std::numeric_limits<int>::max() << std::endl; // requires you to #include <limits>
```

`int` on your system is likely a 32-bit signed two's complement number, which means the max value it can represent is 2,147,483,647. Your number, 3,999,999,999, is larger than that, and can't be properly represented by `int`. `cin` fails, alerting you of the problem.

`long` may be a 64-bit integer on your system, and if it is, try that. You need a 64-bit integer to represet 3,999,999,999. Alternatively, you can use an `unsigned int`, which will be able to represent numbers as large as 4,294,967,295 (again, on the typical system). Of course, this means you can't represent negative numbers, so it's a trade-off.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because the big value is too big to fit into a variable of `int` type on your system. Try just assigning the big value to your variable and see what happens.

To fix it, change the type of the variable to a wider type, like `long` or `long long`.

Answer (score 0):

The maximal number representable by an `int` depends on the number of bits it is represented. Usually, it's 32-bits, ie. the maximal number is `2147483647`, which is smaller than the number you typed.

Answer (score 0):

When the formatted input functions fail in some form, they set `std::ios_base::failbit` and leave the original value in the argument unchanged. There are different failures and overflows are considered one sort of failure. I recall a discussion about different errors being indicated in different ways but I din't recall the outcome. The best bet may be to make sure `errno` is cleared before calling any of the input functiins and checking `errno` for `ERANGE` to distinguish an overflow from a format error.